# While loop causing website to vanish

Tags: php, html, css

```
$i = 0;
$sql_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM designs WHERE accessibility=`2` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query) {
    if ($i == "0") { ?><div style="width: 49%; float: left;"><a href="designs.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><img id="lookup_designs_item_icon" src="img/designs/<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $row["resolution"]; ?> | <?php echo $row["artist"]; ?>"/></a></div>
    <?php } elseif ($i == "1") { ?><div style="width: 49%; float: right;"><a href="designs.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><img id="lookup_designs_item_icon" src="img/designs/<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $row["resolution"]; ?> | <?php echo $row["artist"]; ?>"/></a></div>
    <?php } $i++; if ($i == "7") { end while; }
}
```

Why doesn't this code work? If I do it manually without database. You know, just thinking you're PHP and creating the code in HTML and CSS, it works. But as soon as you mix PHP to it, everything goes blank, entire website.

Comment: What does the error log tell? You should learn to use the alternative notation for if statements if you want to mix PHP and HTML like that, since it is easier to see how the control flow from HTML to PHP goes there. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php has more info on that.

Comment: Error log doesn't tell anything new. "You should learn to use the alternative notation for if statements if you want to mix PHP and HTML like that," your link does it just like I did.

Comment: No, you are using still curly braces `{` and `}` in your code. You don't use them with the alternative notation.

Comment: What does `php -l yourfile.php` tell you?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in look.php on line 50
Errors parsing look.php", which 4th line in Pastebin. The "while" thing.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Why should I use alternative notation, if both are correct and not deprecated? I prefer one over another ,there's no reason I can think of to learn both, if one or another have same effect.

Comment: "PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'..." - You are missing a closing parenthesis on your `while` condition. "mix PHP and HTML like that" - just don't mix PHP and HTML like that... it's hard to read/maintain. Build a string of your output (HTML) and echo this once at the end of your loop.

Comment: @w3d Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. You mean using "$table = "<table<tr><td>LOL</td></tr></table>";" and then echo it when required?

Comment: @w3d I don't see the missing "}", Notepad++, clearly says that each { has }, because when you add new "}" it turns red, meaning that there's no starting "{".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query) {
```

> "PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in

As mentioned in comments, you are missing a closing parenthesis (rounded bracket) on your while condition, before the opening brace (squiggly bracket). This should read:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query)) {
```

However, you do have another obvious parse error at the end of your while loop. The following is invalid syntax:

```
if ($i == "7") { end while; }
```

This should read:

```
if ($i == "7") { break; }
```

---

> "mix PHP and HTML like that" - just don't mix PHP and HTML like that... it's hard to read/maintain.

Regardless of syntax used (conventional or *alternative* (that Tero Kilkanen suggests) - which is intended to make this type of code easier to read) you simply should not be mixing PHP and output like this anyway, by dropping out/in of PHP parsing mode.

If you need to construct some HTML to be output later then build a string and `echo` this once at the end of your loop.

So, instead of this:

```
    $i = 0;
            $sql_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM designs WHERE accessibility=`2` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query) {
            if ($i == "0") { ?><div style="width: 49%; float: left;"><a href="designs.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><img id="lookup_designs_item_icon" src="img/designs/<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $row["resolution"]; ?> | <?php echo $row["artist"]; ?>"/></a></div>
            <?php } elseif ($i == "1") { ?><div style="width: 49%; float: right;"><a href="designs.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><img id="lookup_designs_item_icon" src="img/designs/<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $row["resolution"]; ?> | <?php echo $row["artist"]; ?>"/></a></div>
            <?php } $i++; if ($i == "7") { end while; }
    }
```

Do something like this:

```
// HTML to be output
$htm = '';

$i = 0;
$sql_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM designs WHERE accessibility=`2` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query)) {
    if ($i == "0") {
        $htm .= <<<EOD
<div style="width: 49%; float: left;">
    <a href="designs.php?id={$row["id"]}"><img id="lookup_designs_item_icon" src="img/designs/{$row["id"]}.jpg" alt="{$row["resolution"]} | {$row["artist"];}"/></a>
</div>
EOD;
    }
    elseif ($i == "1") {
        $htm .= <<<EOD
<div style="width: 49%; float: right;">
    <a href="designs.php?id={$row["id"]}"><img id="lookup_designs_item_icon" src="img/designs/{$row["id"]}.jpg" alt="{$row["resolution"];} | {$row["artist"];}"/></a>
</div>
EOD;
    }
    $i++;
    if ($i == "7") {
        break;
    }
}

// Output HTML
echo $htm;
```

The code is now much easier to read at a glance and it quickly becomes obvious that there are further optimisations that can be made. For instance...

- the only bit that seems to vary between your `if` blocks is the `float: left` / `float: right` part of your style attribute. So these could be combined.
- `$i` is an integer, yet you are comparing it with a string in your `if` condition. This works, but is not "correct".
- You don't appear to be doing anything in your loop when $i is 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6? So you should be breaking sooner. ie. simply `else { break; }` would seem to do the same thing?

Comment: Such a pathetic mistake of mine! Oh Good Lordy Loo! I can't believe that fathom! How did I miss that!? It indeed missed that one bracket! ")".

Comment: "The code is now much easier to read at a glance and it quickly becomes obvious that there are further optimisations that can be made. For instance...", not in my situation. Notepad++ marks code according to selectors you give it to it. If I use PHP and HTML in your way, it won't color it "properly" so I won't see nothing but flying characters where I won't find difference where HTML or PHP begins.

Comment: It's an easy mistake - done it a lot myself. Although Notepad++ should help to highlight the mismatch.

Comment: "You don't appear to be doing anything in your loop when $i is 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6? So you should be breaking sooner. ie. simply else { break; } would seem to do the same thing?", well, yea, it works now, you solved it. Thanks.

Comment: Well, website is back on, no errors according to terminal's command `php -l xxx.php`. Website displays correctly, but anything within "while" isn't displayed at all. I also tried to write "echo "Hi";" and writing "Hi" through HTML, but it didn't work. CONFIG.php file is included and works because otherwise it would prompt an error. Have you maybe some more time for poor sap like me ;)?

Comment: If you are not getting anything out of your while loop then it would seem that your SQL query is not returning any results. You are using backticks around the column value (ie. `accessibility=``2```) - this is incorrect. Column values should be delimited by single quotes/apostrophe (or nothing at all in the case of numeric fields).